# Introduction to the Maharal

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, maharal

Can someone recommend a work of the Maharal to serve as an introduction to his thought? I have no experience with his work, except where he has been quoted in other books and essays. I don't know where to start.

Comment: The Gur Aryeh is the easiest most *karov el ha'peshat* *sefer* of the Maharal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend reading the essays written by [Rabbi Yitzchok Adlerstein](https://torah.org/series/guraryeh/), there are 47 parashot that are covered in these lessons.

Rabbi Yitzchok Adlerstein explains on the study of the Maharal's work, Gur Aryeh that it is sometimes extremely straightforward (peshat), but sometimes, the Maharal explains things in a philosophical and mystical way:

> Gur Aryeh is sometimes extremely straightforward, analyzing Rashi’s words and the options that Rashi rejected. At other times, Gur Aryeh is deeply philosophical or mystical.

Similary, Rabbi Eliyahu Brin wrote something like a introduction to the Maharal's approach on the website of Yeshiva.co, see: [The Maharal of Prague: An Introduction](https://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/1267)

Rabbi Eliyahu Brin [explains](https://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/1267#:%7E:text=Among%20the%20Maharal%27s,an%20inevitable%20redemption.):

> Among the Maharal's other works, the most important are "Netzach Yisrael," "Tiferet Yisrael," and "Gevurot HaShem." The last of these three works deals with the exodus from Egypt, while each of the previous two deals with the subject of its title: "Netzach Yisrael" - with the Jewish people and their redemption; "Tiferet Yisrael" - with the Torah.
> In a sense, "Netzach Yisrael" is the Maharal's opus magnum. This is because it succeeds, in a few short chapters, in paving the way to a clear understanding of the unique status of the Jewish people and their collective nature. In "Netzach Yisrael" the Maharal drive homes the point that because of their inherent chosen status, the Jewish people are forever advancing toward an inevitable redemption.

---

So, it depends on what you are looking for.

1. If you are looking for his commentary on the Torah; you can study [Gur Aryeh](https://www.sefaria.org/texts/Tanakh/Acharonim%20on%20Tanakh/Gur%20Aryeh/Torah)
2. If you are looking for his work about the exile and redemption, you should check out [Netzach Yisrael](https://www.sefaria.org/Netzach_Yisrael)
3. If you are looking for his work about the Torah and mitzvot, you should check out [Tiferet Yisrael](https://www.sefaria.org/Tiferet_Yisrael). Please note that this is the Tiferet Yisrael from the Maharal and not Tiferet Yisrael (Rabbi Israel Lifschitz, author of Tiferet Yisrael on the Mishnah and Shulchan Arukh). Sefaria offers the free version. However, if you are looking for a version that includes commentary, I would recommend buying [this version from Tiferet Yisrael](https://www.amazon.nl/Prague-Translation-Commentary_Volume-Introduction-Chapters/dp/9655241475)
4. The [Gevurot Hashem](https://www.sefaria.org/Gevurot_Hashem) is also very interesting. It deals with the exodus from Mitzrayim and Pesach Haggadah

You ask:

> Can someone recommend a work of the Maharal to serve as an introduction to his thought?

It seems [Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/Be%27er_HaGolah#:%7E:text=In%20Be%E2%80%99er%20HaGolah,the%20Maharal%E2%80%99s%20works.) might answer this question by saying that Be'er HaGolah, also one of the works from the Maharal, can be viewed as an **introduction to all the works from the Maharal**

> In Be’er HaGolah, the Maharal of Prague (Rabbi Judah Loew ben Bezalel c.1512 - 1609), addresses the critique of his contemporaries on various aspects of Aggadic literature. Through his responses, the Maharal sets out his overall methodology and approach to Aggadah. Be’er HaGolah can be viewed as an introduction to all of the Maharal’s works.

Comment: There is an Artscroll version of Be'er Hagolah, also by Rabbi Adlerstein.

Comment: Indeed, and it contains translations of extracts of the whole work. Very good book. https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781578194636.html

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert myself, but I once saw that Rav Shmuel Auerbach says it is his commentary on Rashi, Gur Aryeh.

Comment: This is all very helpful. Thank you!